# Elusive Ball Game Project

Tags: java, swing, animation, paint, mouselistener

So for our class we're making an elusive ball project. Basically it's a game where the mouse has to chase the circle around until the user gets it. However in my code, the mouse listener is recognizing the mouse moving, but it's not interacting with the circle at all. The ball isn't moving period. I don't know if it's my logic or if I'm using the wrong methods or what.

```
package lab10;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class Lab10 extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener{
int x = 325;
int y = 325;
int rX;
int rY;

public Lab10() {
    super("The Elusive Circle");
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(750,750);
    setVisible(true);

}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawOval(getX(),getY(),80,80);
    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.fillOval(getX(),getY(),80,80);



}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    Lab10 circle = new Lab10();
    System.out.println("MY HEAD!");
}
public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e) {

    System.out.println("bacon pancakes");

}
public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e) {
    setCircle(e);
    System.out.println("my head!!");
}



public void setCircle(MouseEvent m) {
    int getx = m.getX();
    int gety = m.getY();
    Random r = new Random();
    int rX = r.nextInt(700 - 51) + 51;
    int rY = r.nextInt(700 - 51) + 51;
    boolean getxInBounds = (getx == (rX+80));
    boolean getyInBounds = (gety == (rY+80));
    boolean getxInBounds2 = (getx == (rX-80));
    boolean getyInBounds2 = (gety == (rY-89));
    setX(rX);
    setY(rY);
    if(getxInBounds||getxInBounds2||getyInBounds||getyInBounds2){
                repaint();
                }

}
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Idk");
}
private void setX(int a) {
    int x = a;
}
private void setY(int b) {
    int y = b; 
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
```

Comment: `Lab10` looks like homework.  Have you asked your teacher or TA?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `getX()` and `getY()` on your **JFrame** inside of your paint method, and since these never change, the ball never moves. Give your class an xPosition and yPosition field that your MouseMotionListener sets, and use those fields in your paint method.

Edit: you've already got the fields. Set your rX and rY fields. Note, don't call `setX(...)` and `setY(...)` as these set the position of the component, not your circle, and don't give your GUI class `getX()` and `getY()` methods as these will override the component's methods causing nasty side effects.

As an aside, you're far better off drawing inside of the paintComponent method of a JPanel that is displayed in your JFrame.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Hovercraft said, [Swing is not thread safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and all Swing code should be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread.  In your main method, you should [execute the initialization on the EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         Lab10 circle = new Lab10();
         System.out.println("MY HEAD!");
      }
   });
}
```

Otherwise, your code may have "weird bugs" that don't make sense and aren't really debuggable.